# C++ : pass object by reference as Class argument

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

I'm new to C++. I am trying to implement a simple game in a terminal with a `Board` delimited by `*`, with a `Pawn` that can move in the board using zqsd keys.

I want my `Board` to have a `Pawn` argument, so that when I `displayBoard()`, the board knows where the pawn is thanks to `Pawn.getXpos()` and `Pawn.getYpos()`.

To do so in `main.cpp`, I first create a `Pawn` object with positions (1, 1), then I create a board object of 20 chars square. After that, I 'assign' the pawn to the board using `baord.addNewPawn(pawn)`, and that is where the problem is, since I see that my initial pawn in main.cpp and the one that is the board argument are not the same object (since different addresses). I know that it has to do with addresses and pointers, but whatever I tried did not work.

Any help ?

`main.cpp`

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "Board.h"
#include "Pawn.h"
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Pawn pawn{ 1, 1 };
    Board board{ 20, 20 };

    board.addNewPawn(pawn);
    board.initBoard();
    board.displayBoard();

    char input;
    do
    {
        input = _getch();

        int xshift = 0;
        int yshift = 0;

        if (input == 'z')
        {
            yshift = -1;
        }
        else if (input == 'q')
        {
            xshift = -1;
        }
        else if (input == 's')
        {
            yshift = 1;
        }
        else if(input == 'd')
        {
            xshift = 1;
        }
        
        cout << "pawn address " << &pawn << endl;
        pawn.movePawn(xshift, yshift);
        board.displayBoard();

    }while (input != 'x');
    


}
```

`Board.cpp` + `Board.h`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "Board.h"

using namespace std;

Board::Board(int x, int y): m_xsize(x), m_ysize(y)
{
}

void Board::initBoard()
{
    for (int x=0; x<m_xsize; x++)
    {
        vector<char> newline(m_ysize);
        m_board.push_back(newline);
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < m_xsize; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < m_ysize; y++)
        {
            if (x == 0 || y == 0 || x == m_xsize - 1 || y == m_ysize - 1)
            {
                m_board[x][y] = '*';
            }
            else
            {
                m_board[x][y] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }

}

void Board::displayBoard()
{
    cout << "board pawn address " << &m_pawn << endl;

    m_board[m_pawn.getXpos()][m_pawn.getYpos()] = 'o';
    cout << "display " << m_pawn.getXpos() << " " << m_pawn.getYpos() << endl;

    for (int x = 0; x < m_xsize; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < m_ysize; y++)
        {
            cout << m_board[x][y];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void Board::addNewPawn(Pawn pawn)
{
    m_pawn = pawn;
}
```

```cpp
#ifndef BOARD
#define BOARD
#include<vector>
#include "Pawn.h"

class Board
{
public:
    Board(int x, int y);

    void initBoard();
    void displayBoard();
    void addNewPawn(Pawn pawn);


private:
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> m_board;
    int m_xsize;
    int m_ysize;
    Pawn m_pawn;
};
#endif
```

`Pawn.cpp` + `Pawn.h`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "Pawn.h"

using namespace std;

Pawn::Pawn()
{
}
    
Pawn::Pawn(int x, int y): m_xpos(x), m_ypos(y)
{
}

void Pawn::receiveDamage()
{
    m_hp -= 1;
}

void Pawn::movePawn(int x, int y)
{
    
    m_xpos += x;
    m_ypos += y;

    cout << "move pawn " << m_xpos << " " << m_ypos << endl;
}

void Pawn::reward(int turns)
{
    // here
}


int Pawn::getXpos()
{
    return m_xpos;
}

int Pawn::getYpos()
{
    return m_ypos;
}
```

```cpp
#ifndef PAWN
#define PAWN

#include <vector>

class Pawn
{
public:
    Pawn();
    Pawn(int x, int y);

    void receiveDamage();
    void movePawn(int x, int y);
    void reward(int turns);
    int getXpos();
    int getYpos();

private:
    int m_hp = 5;
    int m_xpos = 1;
    int m_ypos = 1;
    std::vector<int> m_history_x;
    std::vector<int> m_history_y;
};

#endif
```

Comment: What is the actual topic in the chapter of your C++ textbook where this practice problem is from. There are many different ways to fix this, you need to point out what specific C++ subject your textbook's chapter is about, this will help in pointing you in the right direction?

Comment: References work poorly as class members, so `m_pawn` should be a pointer: `Pawn *m_pawn;`. The parameter of `addNewPawn` must also become a pointer or a reference (this is up to you, I'd use a reference to signal that you don't want to receive a null pointer).

Comment: your title talks about a reference, and in the text you say its about pointers, but there are no references or pointers. `void addNewPawn(Pawn pawn);` makes a copy. You have one `Pawn` in `main` and another as member of the board, they are two seperate objects

Comment: simply remove the `Pawn` in `main`. YOu do not need 2 of them, use the one that is member of `Board`

Comment: Upvoted for posting properly formatted, complete code so that we can understand the problem. That's already above average.

Comment: Either treat a pawn as having _object semantics_ or as having _value semantics_.  If you treat it like an _object_ then things like "move pawn" make sense, where you change its members x and y, and you should refer to a pawn via a pointer so that you can see its current values should they ever change.  Whereas if you treat it as a _value_ then its members should be unchanging.  It's like "information about a pawn": if you need to describe a pawn at a new location, it's new information and a new value.  (Kind of like notation: "e2-e4". e2 doesn't become e4, they're _before_ and _after_ values.)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik This is not from a textbook, just a radom idea I had for practice purposes (I 'm following an openclassroom though).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai unfortunately i would like to keep my pawn declared outside of my board, so that it is still independant, but I don't know if it makes much sense.

Comment: @Wyck Then is 'treating the pawn like an object' is compatible with HolyBlackCat's answer ? I'm planning to make use of their answer. Then is is possible to have `Pawn *pawn_ptr=&pawn` then modify my `Pawn` object using `*pawn_ptr.getXpos()` or `*pawn_ptr.movePawn()`? Since `*pawn_ptr` supposedly points to a `Pawn` object, so I should be able to use the `Pawn` methods on it ?

Comment: @WillyLutz yes, but rather than `(*pawn_ptr).` everywhere you can use `pawn_ptr->`

Comment: @WillyLutz, yes, you can treat a pawn like an object.  That's perfectly reasonable.  You have a learning journey ahead of you but you're off to a good start now.  So much of modern C++ is about avoiding the bare pointers so that memory management mistakes are avoided.  Your next step might be to learn about _ownership_ and start experimenting with `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and answers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Caleth @HolyBlackCat and @Wick I made it work :

in `Board.h`, I used a pointer `Pawn *m_pawn_ptr`, and gave `addNewPawn` the address of my object.

```cpp
#ifndef BOARD
#define BOARD
#include<vector>
#include "Pawn.h"

class Board
{
public:
    Board(int x, int y);

    void initBoard();
    void displayBoard();
    void addNewPawn(Pawn &pawn);


private:
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> m_board;
    int m_xsize;
    int m_ysize;
    Pawn *m_pawn_ptr;
};
#endif
```

Then to access my Pawn in Board.cpp, I used the arrow operator, like
`m_pawn_ptr->getXpos()`. It worked !
Thank you very much